# Pinescript Strategy.exit trigering unwanted buy or sell positions

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm having an issue with my strategy.exit function
When the take profit is hit it will produces unwanted buy or sell signals instead of waiting for the next entry signal.

Here is my code:

```
// buy signal
 if f_crossed_over() strategy.entry("buy",         strategy.long)
strategy.exit("exitbuy", "buy", profit=profitvalue, comment_profit="TP", loss= stopvalue, comment_loss = "SL")

// sell signal
if f_crossed_under() 
    strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short)
    strategy.exit("exitsell", "sell", profit=profitvalue, comment_profit="TP",  loss=stopvalue, comment_loss="SL")
```

How can I solve this problem?

The strategy.exit should just close the open trade then wait until strategy.entry is triggered again.

Comment: Without all the code we can't reproduce the error and we can't help you